# Linq2Sql Many:Many question, How would you do this?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, many-to-many

I know many:many isn't supported in Linq2Sql but I am working on a workaround

I am working with my little SO clone and I have a table with Questions and a table with Tags and a linking table QuestionTag so I have a classic many:many relationship between Questions and Tags.

To display the list of Questions on the front page I have this class I want to fill up from a Linq2Sql query

```
public class ListQuestion
{
   public int QuestionID { get; set; }
   public string Title{ get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}


public IEnumerable<ListQuestion> GetQuestions()
{
   from q in Questions
   .................
   select new ListQuestion{ ... }
}
```

The problem is how should I fill up the Tag collection. 
I found out this isn't possible to do in 1 single query so I have divided this into 2 queries, 1 to get the questions and 1 to get the tags and later try to join them. 
I know many:many is supported in Entity framework so how do they do it? How would you do this? Any alternative approach? The query should of course be efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work for your case;

```
from q in Questions
select new ListQuestion 
{ 
  Tags = q.QuestionTags.Select(qt => qt.Tag),
  QuestionId = q.ID,
  Title = q.Title
}
```

Comment: It works. Thx a alot. I can't see how the actual query looks like. I would like to avoid that there is fired 1 query for every question to get the tags.

Comment: Does this do TWO round trips to the DB? I've got the same exact question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371279/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-db-round-trips-with-this-linq2sql

Comment: No, there will be only one round trip to the DB.