# Linq to SQL - many to many mapping

Tags: linq-to-sql, orm, linq-to-entities

In my project I have 'Player'(PlayerID and data) table, 'Games' table (GameID, Name) and I made a many to many table 'PlayerGames' (PlayerID, GameID - I created the forign keys relations)

PlayerID and GameID are primary keys in their tables and the tuple (PlayerID,GameID) are primary key in 'PlayerGames' Table

I tried to map these tables in classes using the designer in visual studio.

But in the player class I don't have 'Games' property with a list of games. Instead, I'm having PlayerGames property of type EntitySet.

How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq2Sql Many:Many question, How would you do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368854/linq2sql-manymany-question-how-would-you-do-this)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out [CodeSmith's PLINQO](http://plinqo.com/Home.ashx). It's not free, but it's a super-pimped version of Linq to Sql and it supports many-to-many relationships, among other things.