# C# - Linq many to many with junction table

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many, one-to-many

I've just started using Linq and at the moment I've got a database ready and made some entity classes in C#.

Now my object called "Person" has a many-to-many relationship with "Profession." But whenever I try to call out the next statement it won't work:

```
Context ctx = new Context(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myContext"].ConnectionString);
var Julian = (from j in ctx.persons
                         where j.Name == "Julian"
                         select j).Single();
Profession proftest = new Profession() { Name = "Programmer", Accepted = true };
Julian.Professesions.Add(proftest);
ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Now I'll show you the classes that I'm working with:

Person got the next few things (the rest of the class variable works so I'll show you the bad part):

```
// Data (for mapping)
private EntitySet<PersonProfession> personProfession;

public Person()
        {
            personProfession = new EntitySet<PersonProfession>();
        }


        [Association(Name = "FK_j_Person_Profession_Person", Storage = "personProfession", OtherKey = "personId", ThisKey = "Id")]
        internal ICollection<PersonProfession> PersonProfessions
        {
            get { return personProfession; }
            set { personProfession.Assign(value); }
        }
public ICollection<Profession> Professions
        {
            get { return (from prof in PersonProfessions where prof.Profession.Accepted==true select prof.Profession).ToList(); }
        }
```

Now I am able to call the following method in the "Person" class with success:

```
public void AddProfession(Profession profession, Person person)
        {
            PersonProfession pp = new PersonProfession();
            pp.Person = person;
            pp.Profession = profession;
            personProfession.Add(pp);
        }
```

But ofcourse that's not what I want.

The data relation is like this:

Person --> j_Person_Profession <-- Profession

I've also got the same problem (that the .Add() wont work) with another relation between Person and Alias (which is a table with only an int for PersonId and a String for alias.

---

Last little question is the following:
My "Profession" class also got the same link with "Person", so whenever I ask the context for a person, I can look at his/her profession and within the profession there are more Persons with the same profession. Isn't this very slow with big databases? Maybe I should remove the backward link?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/737308/440704?

Comment: I have now, but my problem is more in the entity code above. I doesn't look like I can find my solution in there. Thanks anyway! Also it seems nobody uses Linq with classes like the above? I see more people just have Data models which they call instead of real code with Associations and stuff.

Comment: it's Linq-to-SQL you are using, aren't you? AFAIK, L2S maps the junction table as an entity, so you have to use the `PersonProfession` object as you do in your working example. In case of Entity Framework as opposed to L2S, a pure junction table (containing only the two foreign keys) would not be mapped to a separate entity, and you could access `Person.Professions` and `Professions.People` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Yakimych's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895538/c-sharp-linq-many-to-many-with-junction-table/6050029#comment6788169_5895538), I got my answer:

> it's Linq-to-SQL you are using, aren't you? AFAIK, L2S maps the junction table as an entity, so you have to use the `PersonProfession` object as you do in your working example. In case of Entity Framework as opposed to L2S, a pure junction table (containing only the two foreign keys) would not be mapped to a separate entity, and you could access `Person.Professions` and `Professions.People` directly.