# LINQ-to-SQL Relationships/Associations

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

It has been awhile since I have worked with Linq-to-Sql, but I am giving it a go again. I am running into an issue where I want to be able to access data a certain way which I thought I have before, but I am not sure now.

If I have the following three SIMPLE tables

```
Person
   - ID

Section
   - ID

PersonSections
   - PersonID
   - SectionID
```

The **PersonSections** table is just a lookup of the Person/Section objects. Therefor it is a one-to-many. One person can be in multiple Sections.

I would like to be able to call this off of the Linq-to-Sql DataContext in the following way.

```
 MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

 var person = db.Sections.First(x => ...).Persons.First(x => x...) etc

 or

 var section = db.Persons.First(x => ...).Sections(x => x...) etc
```

I am trying to find more documentation on the relationships because I am a bit novice when it comes to them, so please be light in your criticism.

Comment: You should probably look at linq to EF, linq2sql is pretty much deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737308/linq-to-sql-many-to-many-mapping

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum - technically, PersonSections allows a many-to-many relationship between Person and Section. If you wanted a one-to-many relationship, this could be represented by adding PersonID to the Section table. However, I'm not sure what the question is here. Is it how to get from Section to Person or vice versa? Have you tried Sections.First().PersonSections.Person?

Answer (score 0):

You mention a one-to-many relationship for person to section.

LINQ2SQL isn't very good with relationship tables so initially I would suggest making the section id a foreign key on the person table.

There is also this post

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39104/LINQ-to-SQL-Many-to-Many-Relationships

Which explains how a many-to-many relationship can be done. This would likely be the same, you can then just add logic in your application to stop the relationship from going both directions.