# How to create many to many relationship in Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a User table, Roles table and a link table User2Roles. I want to create LinqToSQL entities so that I can access roles from user as role.Users and user.Roles manually. Using designer it actually creates 3 entities, User to User2Roles and User2Roles to Roles.

Comment: You know it's generally good policy to either accept an answer, or give further clarification if the answers are not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe that you're stuck with that interim entity. As far as I know Linq to SQL does not support many to many joins in a nice clean way like you're thinking.  There are workarounds in code to make the object model at least *appear* to support many to manys in the way you want.

[Check out this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368854/linq2sql-manymany-question-how-would-you-do-this)

Or this [link](http://www.iaingalloway.com/2015/06/many-to-many-relationships-in-linq-to-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own property in the role and user classes.  The purpose of this property would be to get the users for the current role and return the results as a collection.  Then you can do the same for the other class.

Here is some code without testing (will be replaced once I can get back to my dev box)

```
partial class Roles
{
  List<users> Users
  {
    get { return User2Roles.users.toList(); }
  }
}

partial class Users
{
  List<roles> Roles
  {
    get { return User2Roles.roles.toList(); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually create a many-to-many relationship in Linq to SQL.  However, you can easily create your own "sugar" for it.

```
public partial class User
{
    public IQueryable<Role> Roles
    {
        get { return UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role); }
    }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public IQueryable<User> Users
    {
        get { return UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.User); }
    }
}
```

That's pretty much all there is to it.  This will save you the trouble of always having to deal with the intermediate entity.  You can write code against it as if it were a real M:M relationship:

```
foreach (Role role in user.Roles) { ... }
```

You should even be able to use this in query projections (although you will likely have some problems using it in filters).

Comment: Why IEnumerable?  I would make the properties return IQueryable so as to delay execution...?

Comment: @Eric: Good point.  I think Linq to SQL would recognize that the `IEnumerable` also implements `IQueryable`, but better to make it explicit.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I think you're right.  I suppose IEnumerable is probably just as good, since the query won't execute until you actually move the enumerator to a true value and try and read it.